# Pythonanywhere error when accessing the homepage

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

I get the following error when I access my homepage (on Pythonanywhere). I believe all the settings are correct in the WSGI file. **ImportError: No module named 'myproject'** - even though the module is there. Is this something I have to define somewhere?

The error is as follows:

```
2020-02-19 02:25:26,696: Error running WSGI application
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697: ImportError: No module named 'myproject'
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697:   File "/var/www/user1_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697:     application = get_wsgi_application()
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697: 
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697:   File "/home/user1/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697:     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697: 
2020-02-19 02:25:26,697:   File "/home/user1/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 19, in setup
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698:     configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698: 
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698:   File "/home/user1/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698:     self._setup(name)
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698: 
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698:   File "/home//.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698:     self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2020-02-19 02:25:26,698: 
2020-02-19 02:25:26,699:   File "/home/user1/.virtualenvs/mysite-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
2020-02-19 02:25:26,699:     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
```

Answer (score 0):

On PythonAnywhere, just after your exception in the logs, there is a link to a help page that walks you through debugging import errors in your web app.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was an issue with the path. I dropped the app and re-created it from scratch. Worked like a charm!